# Return distinct data pairs with duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write an SQL query that returns a list of pairs of persons sharing the same city , without duplicates. (This is just test data, as the real database is very random and would be confusing for the question).
Sample data:

```
Person | City
Tom    | New York
Kenny  | Washington
Katja  | New York
Kerry  | New York
Dan    | Washington

Sample return:
Tom, Katja
Kenny, Dan
Kerry,
```

My intuition was the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.person, b.person
FROM People AS a, People AS b
WHERE a.city = b.city;
```

However this returns duplicates in the b column, which is not ideal. 
I've tried a few tweaks but i cannot get it to return distinct values.

Please explain your answer and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pairs, you can do:

```
SELECT p1.person, p2.person
FROM People p1 LEFT JOIN
     People p2
     ON p1.city = p2.city AND p1.person <> p2.person
WHERE p2.person IS NULL OR p1.person < p2.person;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that all people are included, even if there are no matches.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45bca/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

You might find it more convenient to generate a list for each city:

```
select p.city, group_concat(p.person order by p.person)
from people p
group by p.city;
```

Comment: Your second option is much cleaner than my approach! Thank you!
The first option however, is giving me persons on the left and null values on the entire right.

Comment: @AlanmarkKristensen . . . The subtleties of filtering on a self-join like this.  I fixed the answer and provided a SQL Fiddle.